# Cache implementation on ASP.Net Core causes segfault

Tags: c#, segmentation-fault, asp.net-core-2.0, systemd

In a ASP.Net Core app we're using a caching system that implements ConcurrentDictionary for key/value lookup. When running the app on Linux as a service we're getting segfault errors and no obvious errors in order to identify the cause.

If we change to PileCache the errors disappear, but it's a lot slower.
What might be the cause for segfault instead of a regular exception being thrown?
What would cause this to happen only when the app runs through a systemd and not when it's run directly using "dotnet {app}.dll"?

Comment: Probably you have to perform some form of debugging (using logging, [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), events etc.) because it is very hard to tell using given information only. For debugging example check [Where to start with Segmentation Fault (core dumped)](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1490) .NET Core issue discussion on GitHub.

Comment: Segfaults occur when multiple processes are trying to access the same addressable space in memory. As a result, I think this has less to do with your code in particular than your architecture, in general. There's no enough here to properly diagnose the issue, but essentially, there's some process that's going rogue.

Comment: How would this explain that the issue only occurs when the process is running through systemd and not when it's run in a CLI? It's not a bait question, I'm just trying to get some resources that would help me pinpoint the issue.
Or basically, what are the differences when running through systemd and CLI that I could address?

Comment: Hi @Alesito , have you found any reasons for this behavior? We've migrated our .NET Core application to Linux and we're getting similar rare errors. But we have too many usages of `ConcurrentDictionary` and can't just remove them.

Comment: @NikitaDanilov unfortunately we didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: @Alesito oh, and are errors with segfault still reproducible/regular?

Comment: @NikitaDanilov since we couldn't resolve we've moved back to the alternative implementation and haven't tried since. The project has since been retired as well.